# Azure b2c authentication using Mobile Number

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Azure b2c for authenticating the user from web or mobile. By default azure b2c is asking for the email address and if multi-factor authentication is enabled, then it will ask for the phone number to verify.

My Question is will Azure ask for either email or mobile number in the Registration? A user can give phone number and registers, then azure will have to ask for the username (may be, email id is also mandatory). Is this possible in Azure B2C or AWS?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear but if the question boils down to: "Does Azure AD B2C Support Phone Number sign-up?", the answer is "**No, Azure AD B2C does NOT support phone number sign-up yet**".

This is a popular ask that the Azure AD B2C team is reviewing. I'd recommend you vote for this idea to support it and be notified of its progress. You can do so here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334314-phone-number-sign-up

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark it as the answer please or clarify what else you need please?

Comment: If we want to use the phone number as the primary, then we have use custom authentication server or azure for authentication?

Comment: Aws is also having similar services , so the above feature available there

Answer (score 0):

In Azure B2C we can customize the Sign IN flow using [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) it in an public preview. Please Do try on this.